# Modern algebraic topology.

Tags: algebraic-topology, model-categories

Is there any example of a "classic" problem in algebraic topology which was solved using "modern" algebraic topology? (i.e. methods using localizations, category-style theories etc.) Just trying to realize why it is all was created and studied.

Disclaimer: I wonder if i had to add some tags referring to non-concrete type of my question. Please edit or help me with it too.

Comment: Hill-Hopkins-Ravenel resolved the Kervaire invariant one problem, significantly improving our understanding of exotic spheres.

Comment: @MikeMiller: If this is an answer, then you should post it as an answer...

Comment: A good answer to this question should be more than a sentence long.

Comment: @MikeMiller: How about a sentence and a link to a good place where the OP can read more?

Comment: You might enjoy Frank Adams' lovely book *Infinite Loop Spaces*. View it as a report from the battlefield at a time when a lot of the ideas you are interested in where first being created. [May's review](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183544574) of the book is entertaining and available on line.

Answer (score 3):

In the 1950s, Serre proved that a simply connected finite CW-complex (with non-zero reduced homology)
has infinitely many non-trivial homotopy groups, and also conjectured that it should actually have infinitely many non-trivial homotopy groups with 2-torsion. In 1983 McGibbon and Neisendorfer proved this (for all primes $p$ and it has been improved by others since), using Miller's proof of the Sullivan Conjecture (1984), which certainly used its share of modern machinery. This seems to qualify not just because the problem was stated in the 1950s, but because it is fairly straightforward to state and understand, applies to familiar examples, yet was not proved by classical methods.

Comment: A simply connected finite CW-complex can be contractible, for example a simplex.

Comment: I agree! I'd have to chase down Serre's exact wording but it essentially (no pun intended) rules out that case and I edited above to how I've seen it stated by others.